# IF condition in WHERE clause in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I have a query which is used to select the **shift start time** of a user from a table based on the **user_id** and the **time** then. Here I have an if condition to check whether the time he checks in is less than 1 hour early or less than 4 hours late. So the query is supposed to return the `shift_strt_time` if he is not more than 1 hour early and not more than 4 hours late. I want to know whether this is the right way to do it.

```
SELECT shift_strt_time 
FROM shift_attendance 
WHERE user_id = $user_id 
AND if($now >= shift_strt_time,if($now - shift_strt_time < 4*60*60,1,0),if(shift_strt_time - $now  <= 1*60*60,1,0))
```

And one more doubt I have is that, first I wrote the if condition like this,

```
if($now >= shift_strt_time,$now - shift_strt_time < 4*60*60,shift_strt_time - $now  <= 1*60*60)
```

The query worked but I was in doubt about the right syntax of IF inside where clause. Please throw some light on it too.

Comment: Mysql supports conditional where clause, so `if` and `case when` could be used for where clause.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Which if condition is more appropriate? Is there a problem with the second one?

Comment: I am not sure about the logic you are after but in general the if condition works as `if ( [your condition], [if condition true then val or some calculated val],[if condition fails then some val or some calculated value])` , so the 2nd one looks like having correct syntax, its just the logic that you need to fit for this query.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Actually I was not talking about the logic. Did you see the 2 if conditions? Both are similar but in the first I used multiple if conditions and returned 1 and 0 while in the second one I did not return 1 or 0 but the condition itself. That's where I am confused. I know the execution of the first but no idea about the second.

Comment: for the first one you are using if for both cases i.e. when the condition is true or false. if condition will return you true or false and hence you are getting boolean value for the first if condition, and for the 2nd one you are returning some computed values and hence its different than the first one.